# Generating Links from separate sources

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I need a way of a webpage automatically displaying links that are stored in a different file.
I have a way of displaying links that are stored in a JavaScript file using:

```
function set_links()
{
    setHrefById("URLID","URL");
}
function setHrefById(idName, url)
{
    if(document.getElementById(idName))
    {
        document.getElementById(idName).href = url;
    }
}
```

And then in the HTML document using:

```
<A target="_blank" id="URLID" href="">Click here</A>
```

But I want it to be that I insert a link into the JS file and it is then automatically displayed in the HTML webpage.

Is this the best way of achieving this or is there another way of doing this?
I have tried to do this using an Access database but couldn't actually connect to the database and I cannot figure out what the issue is (I have searched Google for a good few hours).

I cannot use a MySQL database because this is running off of a simple intranet.

Comment: I don't fully understand question, but it looks like you just need to create anchors programmatically. If you really stick to client javascript solution, search any simple example of `document.createElement` usage. Sure you can't connect to abstract database from client-side without server-side proxy code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At the moment, the user adds a URL in the JavaScript file and then adds the HTML into the webpage. What I want is to cut out having to add the HTML and have it automatically added. I'm looking into the "document.createElement" method you suggested but I am rather new to JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, there is more fast way - compile string with html and assign it to container. This approach does huge speedup in old browsers. I added code as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have js file with links description:

```
var links = [
   { src: "http://dummy.com", text: "Click here" },
   { src: "http://another.domain", text: "Or here" },
   { src: "../relative/path.html", text: "Or relative one" }
];
```

And container in html page which will store links:

```
<div id="links"></div>
```

For now you need include this script:

```
   var html = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      html += '<a target="_blank" href="' + links[i].src + '">' + links[i].text + '</a>'
   };
   document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = html;
```

Either AFTER div; or in head, but wrap code above in function and call it on body load.

You can play with demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zdfbm/)

Comment: Just hit a slight hitch, how would I be able to splice this array to get hold of the src?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question. In js you have `splice` method of array, but I believe you asking something other. You always can access src of each item via `for` cycle or by index `links[1].src`.